# Flash scrollbar component - removing down/up arrow

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

i just want to remove the down and up arrow from a scrollbar component in flash cs3.
I've tried to remove the movieclips but than the flash would throw errors(which is obvious), than i tried to delete the graphics inside the arrows but with no luck.

Thanks in advance!

Edit: I forgot to mention that i want the actual scrollbar area to expand if i remove the arrows.